# Maven multi-module project: Could not find artifact for parent module

Tags: maven, multi-module

Project contains one module: tfs

```
  archive_service
    |-- tfs
    |      |-- src
    |      |-- pom.xml
    | ---pom.xml
```

Parent pom.xml

```
<project >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>archive_service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <modules>
       <module>tfs</module>
  </modules>

   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

 </project>
```

Child module to be packed in jar.
Pom for tfs Child module:

```
 <project >
     <parent>
        <artifactId>archive_service</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </parent>
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>com.example.tfs</groupId>
     <artifactId>tfs</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.example</groupId>
           <artifactId>archive_service</artifactId>
           <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

</project>
```

Run command  mvn clean install

and receive error:

Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.tfs:tfs:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example:archive_service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

What am I doing wrong?